# Execute linux command in Python Flask

Tags: python, linux, flask

How can I execute linux command inside a Python function? I will run the python file in a linux-based server, and in some functions I want to have something like,

```
def function():
    #execute some commands on the linux system, eg. python /path1/path2/file.py

    # Or execute a shell script, eg. /path1/path2/file.sh
```

What python module do I need to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to just use something like the os.system module to use a command? That's probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 3):

This code will create a flask server and allow you to run commands. You can also capture the output.

```
import subprocess

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

def run_command(command):
    return subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

@app.route('/<command>')
def command_server(command):
    return run_command(command)
```

You can run it by saving above text in server.py

```
$ export FLASK_APP=server.py
$ flask run
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import os, subprocess

# if you do not need to parse the result
def function ():
    os.system('ls')

# collect result
def function(command):
    out = subprocess.run(
        command.split(" "),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    return out.stdout
```